# Insert Hour and Minute to mongoDB date in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to insert a date with user specific time. User will select any time say, 08:30
And I need to insert that time to mongodb with the current date.
I am trying to insert it like this

> new Date().setHours(08,30)

but this gives me something like this **1632272411458**. And I need it to get inserted in the below format

> 2021-09-22T08:30:00.00+00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like

```
var date = new Date();
date.setHours(08, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with date/time values then I always recommend the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library. Would be this:

```
moment().startOf('minute').set({ hour: 8, minutes: 30 }).toDate()
```